# Google AdWords tracking with CF7

Tags: php, wordpress, tracking, google-ads-api, contact-form-7

I would like to use Google AdWords tracking based on event (when people submit). But I would still like to redirect to a thank you page. I have two codes that do the trick, but they do not work together. Is there a way to have the form redirect to another page but still track on submit? When I add these codes at the same time they say that it is already declared.

```html
<?php

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );
 
function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
       location = 'https://revimatch.dk/tak';
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );

function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    typeof goog_report_conversion === 'function' && goog_report_conversion();
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need two functions for this.
You can hook this in one script to your wp_head

```
add_action('wp_head', 'cf7TrackingCode' );
function cf7TrackingCode(){
echo "<script>
      document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
        typeof goog_report_conversion === 'function' && goog_report_conversion();
        location = 'https://revimatch.dk/tak';
      }, false );
    </script>";
}
```

**And very important:

You cant have two functions with the same name in php**